# Getting specific data from a large table pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to process a very large CSV file (4.2 GB) using Pandas, scanning through the file for instances of a specific value. Given the large size of this file, I have tried processing in chunks, but I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm to find instances of the value.

Essentially, I have a set of 33 parameters, several of which can be found in the 4.2 GB table. I have a list of 2,000-odd patients with pneumonia, and I need to find the first instance of each parameter for each patient. The end goal is to create a new table, with one row per patient and each column representing a different parameter. To fill this table, I first have to process the very large table. The large table consists of "Chart Events" for every patient - a patient can have hundreds of events, and the total database includes about 40,000 patients.

I hope to use the new table to train a machine learning algorithm to predict the length of ICU stay for the patients.

My idea so far has been this:

```
for each parameter:
    for every row in chartevents:
        for every patient:
            if the row contains the parameter for that patient:
                update the new table value for that patient and parameter
```

Obviously this is super inefficient, so I was hoping someone might know better way. For more information about the data, check out [this website](https://mimic.physionet.org/).

Comment: Give a try to `Dask` https://dask.org/

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).